# validating nested angular 1.5 components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to validate inner component with no success.

I have a parent component:

```
    <ng-form novalidate name="{{$ctrl.name}}">
      <div class="PaddedArea FloatFar">
        <a class="button " href="#" ng-click="">{{$ctrl.resources.btn_ClearForm}}</a>
        <a class="button primary" href="#" 
           ng-click="appointmentSearch.$valid && $ctrl.search()"
           ng-disabled="appointmentSearch.$invalid">{{$ctrl.resources.btn_Find}}</a>
      </div>
    </ng-form>
```

When i add an input marked as **required** to the above code :

```
<qn-input placeholder="Public Name"
          label="Public Name"
          name="publicName"
          required="true"
          model="$ctrl.template.PublicName">
</qn-input>
<div class="TextError" 
     ng-show="onlineFormTemplate.publicName.$error.required">
    Pulic Name is required field
</div>
```

This line

```
onlineFormTemplate.publicName.$error.required
```

evaluate to true and i see the error message as expected.

I have tried to use this logic with some inner component (3 levels deep).

what i did was:
1. send binding to inner component:

```
    ...
    isRequired: '<',
    requiredMessage:'@',
    formName: '<',
```

2. set select element as required if needed:

```
 ng-required="$ctrl.isRequired"
```

3. and trying to show the message:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 TextError" 
             ng-show="$ctrl.formName.dropdownlist.$error.required && $ctrl.formName.dropdownlist.$dirty">
            {{$ctrl.requiredMessage}}
        </div>
```

With no success.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong or not doing at all ?

thanks

Comment: I am wondering if my question is "ok" due to lack of answers.I would be happy to hear any other ways to implement error handling with nested components.no need to correct me about angulr-message.it is known.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?